# How to design a custom UIButton in a XIB file?

Tags: ios, uibutton, xib

I'm trying to create a custom UIButton for a Radio Button class.  When selected, the button should have a background color of orange with a text color of white, and when unselected it should have a background color of white with a text color of black.  I was able to do this programmatically by adding a colored UIView below the button's text label, but I was hoping to do this with a XIB file.  However, I can't for the life of me find an online tutorial for designing a UIButton in a XIB file.  Is there a way to do this?  Could anyone tell me how or point me to a tutorial?

Edit: For clarity, I am using storyboards.  I'm not talking about a xib file for the entire view controller.  I'm talking about making a XIB file ONLY for the one button.  Is this possible?

Comment: Simply create a subclass of UIButton then assign it to your control

Comment: I've already created a subclass of UIButton.  How do I attach it to the xib file though? See edit for clarification. @meda

Comment: You dont need a xib file dor this, u put the button on your storyboard then you assign it that class just like you would with with a viewcontroller

Comment: But I want a reusable custom button.  By just putting it in a view controller I can't reuse it @meda

Comment: Copy paste it as many times as you wish to reuse it?

Comment: So you're saying it's not possible to design it in a xib? I know all the ways I could get around it but I was hoping to do it this way. @meda

Comment: @JohnFarkerson did you find out how to do it? I'm facing the same situation

Answer (score 5):

This is a little bit old.. Anyway, this is how I managed to do it on Xcode 10.1 and Swift 4.2.

1. Create a .xib file, let's say `CustomButton.xib` and put a UIView `contentView` in it
2. Create a .swift file, calling it the same, so `CustomButton.swift`
3. Open the .swift file and define the custom class as follows:

> ```
> import UIKit
>
> class CustomButton: UIButton {
>
> }
> ```

4. Now open the .xib and select `contentView`, then Size -> Freeform in the Attributes Inspector. In this way you can manipulate the `contentView` size in IB
5. **IMPORTANT**. In the Identity Inspector, do not assign the custom class to `contentView`, i.e., the main view of the .xib. Assign it to the File's Owner instead

   [image] -----> [image]

   [image] -----> [image]

   (if you have "Inherit Module From Target" selected, leave the "Module" selection to Xcode)
6. Now you should be able to *ctrl-drag* the `contentView` in its class file and have an outlet to reference it
7. Create the initializers in your class, as follows.

> ```
> @IBOutlet weak var contentView: UIView!
>
> //  init used if the view is created programmatically
> override init(frame: CGRect) {
>     super.init(frame: frame)
>     self.customInit()
> }
>
> //  init used if the view is created through IB
> required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
>     super.init(coder: aDecoder)
>     self.customInit()
> }
>
> //  Do custom initialization here
> private func customInit()
> {
>     Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("CustomButton", owner: self, options: nil)
>
>     self.addSubview(self.contentView)
>     self.contentView.frame = self.bounds
>     self.contentView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleHeight, .flexibleWidth]
> }
> ```

Now you should be able to design your CustomButton with .xib and use it wherever you want.

Comment: What is the first line in your customInit meant to do? Don't you need to call .first to retrieve the view, and then add it into the content view?

Comment: I did it the same way, but button is not clickable. any idea how to make it clickable?

Answer (score 0):

1. You can configure background color without XIB file - you need to create a subclass of UIButton and override **isHighlighted** property like this:

   import UIKit

   class OverlayButton: UIButton {

   ```
    override var isHighlighted: Bool {
        didSet {
            if isHighlighted {
                backgroundColor = .orange
                tintColor = .white
            } else {
                backgroundColor = .white
                tintColor = .black
            }
        }
    }
   ```
2. If you want to create a custom button with XIB file - you can create a custom view as @martin described above and **put a UIButton over the whole view**. Make it's **backgroundColor = .clear** for normal state and **some other color for highlighted state**.

[image: List item]

Answer (score -3):

> I'm talking about making a XIB file ONLY for the one button

There is actually a way which I haven't tested yet but I don't think it's recommended by Apple since the option to create a new xib is disabled when you're adding a new button subclass

There are 2 alternatives to create reusable buttons depends on where you want to put the button's implementations:

1. Set the button appearance via IB / storyboard and just copy the button where you need it, you don't even need subclass in your case https://i.stack.imgur.com/e8gDC.jpg
2. Set the colors (or other appearances) via code and connect it to the buttons on storyboard. The downside of this method is you don't see the changes on xcode unless you use IBDesignable https://i.stack.imgur.com/c064a.jpg

You can definitely combine both the methods above. Set some properties via interface builder, then set some other properties via code under `- (void)awakeFromNib`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Mind telling me the untested way that you mentioned?

Comment: I did make reusable views using xib. I expect it also works with buttons since UIButton is inherited from UIView. This [blog](http://www.maytro.com/2014/04/27/building-reusable-views-with-interface-builder-and-auto-layout.html) makes a good explanation on how to do it. It's not simple and still have downsides (explained in the blog) which is why I don't recommend doing it unless you have more complicated views / buttons. Please upvote or mark my answer as correct if it helps you, I'm new here and it will mean a lot :)